# How to count (CountIf) cells in Excel if it's duplicated more than 2 times, and the date on the same row for these cells is in the future?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet, with a column shows date, another column contains name, more entries come in in the new rows and I want to make sure that the name isn't written more than 2 time where the date for that cell row is in the future (>today()).

Example:

| Date | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17/9/2023 | Joseph | John | Martin |
| 17/9/2023 | John | Martin | Ahmad |
| 18/9/2023 | Ali | Alina | Sara |
| 19/9/2023 | **Martin** | Ahmad | Sara |
| 19/9/2023 | **Sara** | **John** | Ali |

So the criteria should see these names in bold!

I tried the following but it's showing an error:

```
=COUNTIFS($G$30:$J$41,G30,$C$30:$C$41,C30)>2
```

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(($G$30:$J$41=G30)*($C$30:$C$41<C30))>=2`

Comment: All of the dates are in the future therefore Martin in row one should be bold as well - or is there another logic?

Comment: Yes, this formula is to be filled in the validation custom field, so it should detect the last entry when written down and then trigger the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula-

```
=LET(x,FILTER(B2:D6,A2:A6>TODAY()),y,MAP(x,LAMBDA(t,SUM(--(t=x)))),ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(TOCOL(x),TOCOL(y)>2))))
```

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier, I'll use the formula in the data validation "Custom" field, so it returns a bolean that will trigger an error message, so if the name already exists 2 times in future dates then the error will appear when the user is trying to fill the same name for the 3rd time!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correct - you can use this formula:

`=AND($G30>=TODAY(),SUMPRODUCT(($G$30:$G$34>=TODAY())*($H$30:$J$34=H30))>=2)`

[image]

In my example first two rows are in the past --> no count, no highlightning

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier, I'll use the formula in the data validation "Custom" field, so it returns a bolean that will trigger an error message, so if the name already exists 2 times in future dates then the error will appear when the user is trying to fill the same name for the 3rd time! –

Comment: yes - you can use this as formula in data validation. That's how the orange background is generated